# Grow windows form with button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to grow a  form when I click the button and it should be in the center of the screen .so I wrote following code snippet.

```
private void ord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Size = new Size(1308,599);                
    this.Show(); 
}
```

But when I click the button window grows but half of the window can not see.Here is the picture of that.

[GUI after growing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI59h.png)

How can I get rid of this problem.?

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You might try repositioning your window after you grow it.

Comment: First grow it, then center it

Comment: @JoshPart I tried it.But didn't work.

Comment: @car then update your code

Comment: Additional to given answers, In cases which you want to move the `From` to center of screen using a `Button`, you can simply use `this.CenterToScreen()` without any problem. Also if the `Form` is currently at center of screen, then it's enough to get the `DesktopBound` and put it in a variable, `Inflate` it and then assign the variable to `DesktopBound` property again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PrimaryScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [`Screen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
//this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
//this.Show();
```

Omit these lines you've written, except setting the `Size` property of the form:

```
private void ord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(1308,599); 
    CenterForm();
}
```

Create a method named `CenterForm()` which will set a new location of the form. You can achieve this by calling this method in your button click event.

```
private void CenterForm()
{
    int getWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int getHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    int X = getWidth - this.Width;
    int Y = getHeight - this.Height;
    this.Location = new Point(X / 2, Y / 2);
}
```

***Note:*** *Always remember to [anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) your controls when the size of the form has changed.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to *compute* both `Size` and `Location`:

```
private void ord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Ensure that suggested form size doesn't exceed the screen width and height
  this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(
    Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width >= 1308 ? 1308 : Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width,
    Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height >= 599 ? 599 : Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height);

  // locate the form in the center of the working area 
  this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(
     (Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width - Width) / 2,
     (Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height - Height) / 2);
}
```